# How can I create a dummy multi-threaded process and get its tids using common utilities?

Tags: linux, terminal, multithreading

I can make a dummy process that will hang forever and get its PID with:

```
bash -c 'echo $$; read'
```

I'd like a multi-threaded alternative to this one-liner which creates 2+ threads, prints the thread ids of each thread, then every thread blocks. Usage would look something like:

```
$ launch-multithread
2459
2460
```

Is this possible with common Unix utilities?

For the curious, I'd like to do this because I'm playing with cgroups and want to avoid messing with any processes doing something I care about.

Comment: Hmm this works but I hate having an inline python program: `sh -c 'python3 -c "import threading, time; threading.Thread(target=lambda: time.sleep(50)).start(); time.sleep(50)" & sleep 1; ls /proc/$!/task;'`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple way to accomplish your goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sh -c "sleep 3600" &
echo $!
sh -c "sleep 3600" &
echo $!
```

Using `sleep 3600` will keep your process alive for 1 hour - adjust as needed.

Comment: That launches multiple processes, none of which are multi-threaded.

Comment: Yes, these _are_ processes.  On Linux, process IDs and thread IDs are allocated from the same numbering space, so I thought this would suffice.

Comment: Yeah this would work in many situations. However, I need a multi-threaded single process.